# AndroidStudio + android-apt + Android Annotations: IDE removes generated folder from include path

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-annotations

I'm currently migrating my project to the new IDEA-based IDE. Current Gradle plugin version as per the `build.gradle`file is 0.12.

In order to make the Android Annotations code generator to work, I followed the instructions from [this link](http://www.jayway.com/2014/02/21/androidannotations-setup-in-android-studio/) and got it seldom working (couldn't reproduce it though).

From the gradle log, I can see apt is actually generating code, which is being saved on `main-project/sub-project/build/source/...`. I also noticed, though, that every time the project is built, this folder is removed from the build path (so the generated classes are not recognized). These lines are automatically added to the `sub-project.iml`file (as the iml file is also generated, manually changing it wont do anything):

```
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/intermediates" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/outputs" />
  <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/build/source" />
```

If I try to check `Preferences > Compiler > Excludes`, nothing is shown there.

I guess the right thing to do would be to point APT to generate the code inside `sub-project/build/generated/...`, which is also the folder used to put default Android generated code (R, etc), and it is not excluded from the path. But how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The instructions on the link I mention above refer to the 1.2 version of `android-apt`. Changing the dependency version from 1.2 to 1.3 solves the problem.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+'
    classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.3+'
}
```

The apt generation folder has been fixed recently on android-apt as per this [commit](https://bitbucket.org/hvisser/android-apt/commits/1edfb4bc3cedd8b4b659742a1e8d0c353962ebf8?at=default).